# generate zip file grouping multiple pdf, using servlet and itext 7

Tags: java, pdf, servlets, itext, zip

I'm trying to put multiple generated pdf into a zip from servlet using itext7, I've managed to put one pdf in a zip file but not more. Here is the code:

```
private void printMore(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws SQLException {
        String masterPath = req.getServletContext().getRealPath("/assets/template/templateStatement.pdf");
        try (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(masterPath);
             ZipOutputStream zipFile = new ZipOutputStream(resp.getOutputStream());
             PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(zipFile);
             PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
             Document doc = new Document(pdf)) {

            List<Student> studentList = getFactoryDAO().getStatementDAO().selectStudentHasBalance();
            for (Student student : studentList){

                // Generate PDF for the student

                PdfPage page = pdf.getPage(1);
                PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);

                FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont();
                PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontProgram, "utf-8", true);
                canvas.setFontAndSize(font, 10);

                canvas.beginText();

                canvas.setTextMatrix(178, 650); // student code
                canvas.showText(student.getS_Code());

                canvas.setTextMatrix(200, 610); // Date of Statement
                canvas.showText(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date()));

                canvas.endText();

                float[] pointsWidth = {60f,120f,70f,70f};
                Table table = new Table(pointsWidth);
                table.setMarginTop(280);
                table.setMarginLeft(70);
                table.setFont(font);
                table.setFontSize(10);
                table.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
                //Header Table
                table.addCell(new Cell().add("Date Inscription"));
                table.addCell(new Cell().add("Name"));
                table.addCell(new Cell().add("Fees"));
                table.addCell(new Cell().add("Observation"));
                //Detail Table
                table.addCell(new Cell().add(student.getTxnDate()));
                table.addCell(new Cell().add(student.getS_FullName));
                table.addCell(new Cell().add(student.getFees));
                table.addCell(new Cell().add(student.getObservation));
                

                doc.add(table);


                ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(student.getS_Code() + "_" + student.getS_LName() + ".pdf");
                zipFile.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                //zipFile.write(); Shall I use it?

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        resp.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachement; filename=test.zip");
        resp.setContentType("application/zip");
    }
```

I've based on this [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158138/how-to-dynamically-generate-pdf-using-servlet) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511389/zip-a-pdf-file-created-using-itext) but doesn't work. I already check more post like [this](https://javatorch.wordpress.com/2013/09/19/generate-a-pdf-using-itext-as-a-byte-array/) but the version of itext7 has no PdfWriter.getInstance as mentionned. I've tried more thing but can't managed to go furthermore.

UPDATED :

After Enterman suggestion i updated it like this :

```
String masterPath = req.getServletContext().getRealPath("/assets/template/templateStatement.pdf");
        try (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(masterPath);
             ZipOutputStream zipFile = new ZipOutputStream(resp.getOutputStream());
             PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(zipFile);
             PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(reader, writer)
             ) {

            List<Student> studentList = getFactoryDAO().getStatementDAO().selectStudentHasBalance();
            for (Student student : studentList){

                try (Document doc = new Document(pdf)){
                       // Generate PDF for the student

                PdfPage page = pdf.getPage(1);
                PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);

                FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont();
                PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontProgram, "utf-8", true);
                canvas.setFontAndSize(font, 10);

                canvas.beginText();

                canvas.setTextMatrix(178, 650); // student code
                canvas.showText(student.getS_Code());

                canvas.setTextMatrix(200, 610); // Date of Statement
                canvas.showText(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date()));

                canvas.endText();

                float[] pointsWidth = {60f,120f,70f,70f};
                Table table = new Table(pointsWidth);
                table.setMarginTop(280);
                table.setMarginLeft(70);
                table.setFont(font);
                table.setFontSize(10);
                table.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
                //Header Table
                table.addCell(new Cell().add("Date Inscription"));
                table.addCell(new Cell().add("Name"));
                table.addCell(new Cell().add("Fees"));
                table.addCell(new Cell().add("Observation"));
                //Detail Table
                table.addCell(new Cell().add(student.getTxnDate()));
                table.addCell(new Cell().add(student.getS_FullName));
                table.addCell(new Cell().add(student.getFees));
                table.addCell(new Cell().add(student.getObservation));
                

                doc.add(table);


                ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(student.getS_Code() + "_" + student.getS_LName() + ".pdf");
                zipFile.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                //zipFile.write(); Shall I use it?
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        resp.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachement; filename=test.zip");
        resp.setContentType("application/zip");
```

But still no luck.

Your help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using a FileInputStream, like below (code of my own, working well in production)

```
private File createZip(List<File> forZip, LocalDate date) {

    String zipName = Constants.ORDER_FILE_PATH + date.getYear() +"-" + date.getMonth().getValue() + "-" + date.getMonth().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.FRENCH) + ".zip";

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(zipName);
        ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
        for (File srcFile : forZip) {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
            ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(srcFile.getName());
            zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
            }
            fis.close();
            //srcFile.delete();
        }
        zipOut.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("createZip", e);
    }

    return new File(zipName);
}
```

Comment: Hello BenjaminD, thank you for your help. Could you please show me how can i use it into my code, please? I'm pretty new on Outputing File with servlet/jee. thank you.

Comment: I gave you the whole method. The Date parameter only helps if you want to name your archive file after the time it is created. You can remove it if you want. Understand the modularity of code. First, create the PDF files. Then, when this is done, give the list of files to the method and it will create the archive. The commented line is if you want to delete a file after it's been added toe the archive.

Comment: Your code is very clear. The proble is how i get the PDF file after doc.addTable? Let me check something if can get it :p

Comment: You should split your problem in two parts : 1 - How to generate PDF files with iText. 2 - How to add multiple files to a zip archive. You already have part 2. Let's look at part 1 now.

Comment: There is a good tutorial on iText here : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/itext/index.htm with a section  for canvas as there were one in your example. Canvas are for drawing. If you want text, use a paragraph.

Comment: Thank you a lot BenjaminD. Last question please, when received the zipFile as File, how can the servlet serves it? FileOutput? ZipOutput?

Comment: I'm not very skilled in servlets so I prefer to say nothing instead of saying something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks for BenjaminD, Enterman for their support and all stack community.

I post this answer for those who has faced the same problem as me. (I've been stuck for 4 days). "Generating multiple PDF with itext 7 and servlets"

As Enterman said : "need new Instance of Document". In addition need PdfDocument also. And as BenjaminD instruction : "Generate a file PDF first, after put them into a zip".

```
String masterPath = req.getServletContext().getRealPath("/assets/template/templateStatement.pdf");
        try (ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(resp.getOutputStream())) {

            Liste<File> listFile = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Student> studentList = getFactoryDAO().getStatementDAO().selectStudentHasBalance();
            for (Student student : studentList){
                
                File file = new File(student.getS_Code()+"_"+new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date())+".pdf");
                try (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(masterPath), new PdfWriter(file.getName()))
                     Document doc = new Document(pdf)){
                       // Generate PDF for the student

                PdfPage page = pdf.getPage(1);
                PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);

                FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont();
                PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontProgram, "utf-8", true);
                canvas.setFontAndSize(font, 10);

                canvas.beginText();

                canvas.setTextMatrix(178, 650); // student code
                canvas.showText(student.getS_Code());

                canvas.setTextMatrix(200, 610); // Date of Statement
                canvas.showText(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date()));

                canvas.endText();

                float[] pointsWidth = {60f,120f,70f,70f};
                Table table = new Table(pointsWidth);
                table.setMarginTop(280);
                table.setMarginLeft(70);
                table.setFont(font);
                table.setFontSize(10);
                table.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
                //Header Table
                table.addCell(new Cell().add("Date Inscription"));
                table.addCell(new Cell().add("Name"));
                table.addCell(new Cell().add("Fees"));
                table.addCell(new Cell().add("Observation"));
                //Detail Table
                table.addCell(new Cell().add(student.getTxnDate()));
                table.addCell(new Cell().add(student.getS_FullName));
                table.addCell(new Cell().add(student.getFees));
                table.addCell(new Cell().add(student.getObservation));
                

                doc.add(table);


                listFile.add(file);
                }

            }
            
            File zipFile = createZip(listFile, 
            newSimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date())); //BenjaminD source in answer

            ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(zipFile.getName);
            zipEntry.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
            fileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
            }
            fis.close();

            resp.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachement; filename=" + zipFile);
            resp.setContentType("application/zip");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It will put the zip in a zip (can Directly use FileOutpuStream to not put it again in a zip).

Thank you again.